# Make the properties of a mapped entity read-only

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    private Person person;
}

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    // ... many more properties which should be read-only
}
```

Sometimes the `name` of the mapped `Person` is modified, and `Hibernate` generates update statements. But I don't want these to happen.

Is there a way to mark the properties of the mapped `person` read-only?

Changes to the id of the mapped `person` (I mean, a different `person` is attached to `MyEntity`) should however still make `Hibernate` update `MyEntity`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Column(updatable=false)`

From the docs:updatable (optional): whether or not the column will be part of the update statement (default true)

Comment: Does this take into account that I still want that the person of myEntity can be change. Only it's properties like "name" should be read-only. (I added information to the question for clarity)

Comment: Yes, by putting `@Column(updatable=false)` on `Person` 's `name` only that column will be left out when updating `Person` entity. It shouldn't stop you from assigning a different person to your parent entity.

Comment: Ok. I have trouble explaining what I need... I want to update Persons in general. Only not if they while mapped to an MyEntity.